# SignalR - Not calling OnReconnected using long polling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, long-polling

From what I have read a SignalR client should not miss any messages from the server while it's connected. This does not seem to be the case when using long polling.

I have a straightforward hub based application using SignalR 1.1.2. When using SSE, if the network cable is unplugged and plugged back in again within the timeout period, both the client and server are notified that a reconnect has occurred and, as far as I can tell, no messages are missed. When  using long polling, this seems to happen:

- When the connection is created ($.connection.hub.start()) the OnConnected method is called in the hub and the client goes into connected state.
- If I then unplug the network cable and pop it back in quickly, there is no call to OnDisconnected or OnConnected. No messages are missed. Any messages waiting on the server are subsequently sent to the client. OK so far.
- If I unplug the network cable and let the long poll expire, I get a call to OnDisconnected. There is no state change on the client.
- If I plug the network cable back in the client starts receiving messages again. There has been no notification on the client that it has been disconnected, but the client has missed some messages. There is no call to OnReconnected or OnConnected on the server.

Is this a bug? The behaviour seems very different between SSE and long polling.
Is there a recommended strategy to ensure that the client does not miss messages in this scenario? I could keep track of connection ids on the server and send periodic pings from the client - if I get a ping after an OnDisconnected I could send a message to tell the client to resync, but this doesn't seem like the right thing to do.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets, Server Sent Events, and Forever Frame all utilize a client side keep alive which is used to ensure client connectivity.  However, Long Polling does not utilize the client side keep alive feature due to technical limitations and has no guarantee of connectivity for events such as pulling the network cable out.

When I say no guarantee I'm simply stating that the Long Polling transport is no longer able to be ensured by SignalR but instead relies on the Browser to trigger the correct events  on Long Polling's ajax connection (through which SignalR can respond to).

Keep in mind though, if the client does happen to regain connectivity with the server after pulling out the network cable it will receive any messages that it missed during its down time.  So messages are not missed, they're just delayed.

Lastly in the case that the server does not see the client for an extended period of time the OnDisconnected event WILL be triggered.  For this to happen in a situation such as pulling the network cable out the server will first timeout the current connection's request and then will timeout the connection itself. This means that you can still rely on the OnDisconnected event, it may just be delayed based on network conditions.

Soooo what you're seeing is 100% by design =)

Hope this helps!